# Multilingual Open Graph objects?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, localization

For a Facebook game, I want to have Open Graph picture objects with titles in multiple languages (specifically, English and German). I did everything as described in Facebooks open graph [internationalization document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/), but somehow the objects (and actions) are always shown with English titles in the newsfeed and activities - and the app is definitely localized in its configuration.

Here's the URL of one of the objects: http://apps.facebook.com/spot-it/opengraph/picture/pictures.1A24.html

If I get it through Facebook's object debugger using the fb_locale parameter [set to German](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://apps.facebook.com/spot-it/opengraph/picture/pictures.1A24.html?fb_locale=de_DE), I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# spot-it: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/spot-it#">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="de_DE">
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US">
<meta property="og:locale" content="de_DE">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="419035224820013">
<meta property="og:type" content="spot-it:picture">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://apps.facebook.com/spot-it/opengraph/picture/pictures.1A24.html">
<meta property="og:title" content="Beißerchen">
<meta property="og:description" content="Findest du die Fehler in 'Beißerchen'?">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://d2tv32y5kdvj8c.cloudfront.net/assets/pictures/1A24_potd.jpg">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    self.location.href = "";
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So why doesn't Facebook use the German version when displaying actions involving that object to German users? Am I doing something wrong, or does internationalization for open graph simply not work?

Comment: I'm *exactly* having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I am having the same exact issue, any solution?

Comment: Mentioning these being HTML meta tags, they should also have [lang attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang) but I don't bet on Facebook supporting that.

Answer (score -2):

in the app settings at [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/) > your app > "Localize" you can add support for additional languages.

you can set:

- display name
- tagline
- description
- detailed description
- explanation for permissions
- and all images like logo, icon, web banner, cover image…

i hope this is what you're looking for ;)

Comment: No, sorry :) That is about the translation of your app. This question is about Open Graph objects.